# Why does a function in nested XPATH conditional cause the error?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is a question about an "xpath expression is invalid" error received from a webDrv.find_elements_by_xpath() call.

**Background**

While searching a jobs website for elements containing target job title text, e.g., "scrum master" (normalized to lower()), found in an element such as

```
<a href="/jobs/view/1836192833/">
    Scrum MASTER
</a>
```

the Selenium-Python query...

`aJobTitle = getNormalJobTitle(...)  # to match "scrum master" with "Scrum Master" "SCRUM Master" etcA
s = '// *[contains(translate(text(),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPURSTUWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopurstuwxyz"), "' + aJobTitle + '")]'
jobNodes = webDrv.find_elements_by_xpath(s)`

works perfectly. All "Scrum MASTER," "Scrum Master," Scrum master," etc. elements returned.

However, when a website -- for whatever reasons -- includes other elements, e.g.,

`<a href="/jobs/view/1836192833/"> Scrum Master <!----> </a>`

the query above finds nothing.

Using a different xpath form -- and working without the lower() normalization...

`s = "//*[text()[contains(.,'" + "Scrum MASTER" + "')]]"
jobNodes = webDrv.find_elements_by_xpath(s)`

works perfectly.  All, and only, "Scrum MASTER" elements returned (but not "Scrum Master," etc., of course)

**My Problem**

However, when I try to search using a normalized job title in lowercase by substituting the call to `text()` with a call to `translate(text(),,)`...

`aJobTitle = getNormalJobTitle(...) # "scrum master"
s = "//*[translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')[contains(.,'" + aJobTitle + "')]]"`

I'm treated to

`Exception has occurred: InvalidSelectorException
Message: Given xpath expression "//*[translate(tex(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')[contains(.,'scrum master')]]" is invalid:
[Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x80600008 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/element.js :: element.findByXPathAll :: line 410"  data: no]
  File "C:myfile.py JS.py", line 41, in <module>
    jn = liJobsElement.find_elements_by_xpath(s)`

So finally...

1) Why does the addition of a function cause the error?
2) How might I achieve the normalization such that I can find all case forms of, e.g., a job title?

Comment: The error message containis `tex()` - should that be `text()`?

Comment: Hmmm.  I must have biffed a "t" during the arduous task of writing and formatting; my first formatting effort on the stackoverflow boards.  Thanks!  Good eye!

Just re-ran it in VSCode debugger:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//*[translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')[contains(.,'scrum master')]]" is invalid: [Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x80600008 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/element.js :: element.findByXPathAll :: line 410"  data: no]

Comment: The expression quoted in the error message is legal XPath, even in XPath 1.0.

Comment: Yet here we are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write : `translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')[`

You can't use a predicate with a string (i.e. : the output of `translate` function). That's why your XPath is invalid. What can be tested are elements, attributes, and `text()` nodes.

Regarding your problem, your first XPath looks fine to me. But some XPath engines doesn't consider it valid. Working XPath could be :

With `normalize-space` function (we remove `contains` function) :

```
//*[translate(normalize-space(),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")="scrum master"]
```

With context item `.` (instead of the problematic `text()`), but we have to specify the element name (`a`) or add a predicate (no children element) :

```
//a[contains(translate(.,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPURSTUWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopurstuwxyz"),"scrum master")]

//*[contains(translate(.,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPURSTUWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopurstuwxyz"),"scrum master")][count(./*)=0]
```

So, to sum up you could use something like :

```
s = '//*[translate(normalize-space(),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")="%s"]'%str(aJobTitle)
jobNodes = webDrv.find_elements_by_xpath(s)
```

or

```
s = '//a[contains(translate(.,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPURSTUWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopurstuwxyz"),"%s")]'%str(aJobTitle)
jobNodes = webDrv.find_elements_by_xpath(s)
```

or

```
s = '//*[contains(translate(.,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPURSTUWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopurstuwxyz"),"%s")][count(./*)=0]'%str(aJobTitle)
jobNodes = webDrv.find_elements_by_xpath(s)
```

Comment: Fantastic, E! The penultimate and final forms did the trick!  Very arcane solution; haven't seen normalize-space() mentioned in all of my searching.  Will try to learn about that function.  Many thanks!